# Why isn't NVRTC optimizing out my integer division and modulo operations?

Tags: optimization, cuda, compiler-flags, nvrtc

I compiled a kernel in NVRTC:

```
__global__ void kernel_A(/* args */) {
    unsigned short idx = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned char warp_id = idx / 32;
    unsigned char lane_id = idx % 32;
    /* ... */
}
```

I know integer division and modulo are very costly on CUDA GPUs. However I thought this kind of division-by-power-of-2 should be optimized into bit operations, until I found it isn't:

```
__global__ void kernel_B(/* args */) {
    unsigned short idx = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned char warp_id = idx >> 5;
    unsigned char lane_id = idx & 31;
    /* ... */
}
```

it seems `kernel_B` just runs faster. When omitting all other codes in kernel, launching with 1024 blocks of size 1024, `nvprof` shows `kernel_A` runs for **15.2us** in average, while `kernel_B` runs **7.4us** in average. I speculate NVRTC did not optimize out the integer division and modulo.

The result is obtained on a GeForce 750 Ti, CUDA 8.0, averaged from 100 calls. The compiler options given to `nvrtcCompileProgram()` is `-arch compute_50`.

Is this expected?

Comment: You don't need to speculate. Run the executables through `cuobjdump -sass` to find out.

Comment: @tera I'm doing JIT compilation via NVRTC so there's no executable file. Any way of getting assembly dumped?

Comment: NVRTC emits PTX and passes it to the driver for JIT compilation. You can extract the PTX with `nvrtcGetPTX `. Then you don't need to speculate

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the tip, will try to investigate more.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should actually not bother with either of these; the warp and lane id are available [for free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337309/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-calculate-the-warp-id-and-lane-id-in-a-1-dimens).

Comment: I think its unlikely there is any difference between the two cases shown.  When compiling all the way to SASS with nvcc, the produced code  (both PTX **and** SASS) in each case is identical.   I think it's unlikely that nvcc source->PTX followed by JIT of PTX->SASS would be any different.  Since a full repro case is not given in this question, my guess is that the difference lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a thorough bugsweep in the codebase. Turns out my app was built in `DEBUG` mode. This causes additional flags `-G` and `-lineinfo` passed to `nvrtcCompileProgram()`

From `nvcc` man page:

> `--device-debug` `(-G)`
>
> Generate debug information for device code. Turns off all optimizations.
>          Don't use for profiling; use -lineinfo instead.